# Accessor Descriptor: How to use 'get' and 'set' in practice?

Tags: javascript, get, set, getter-setter, ecmascript-5

I am not sure if I am getting it right.

This example is straight from MDN (Mozilla Developer Network):

```
var bValue;  
Object.defineProperty(o, "b", {get : function(){ return bValue; },  
                               set : function(newValue){ bValue = newValue; },  
                               enumerable : true,  
                               configurable : true});
```

What happens is - it creates a global variable named bValue, which is not done. I understand that this example only demonstrates the use and thus it is okay if it creates a global variable. But if I am going to use this in an application, I will modify it slightly, by adding the `this` keyword:

```
Object.defineProperty(o, "b", {get : function(){ return this.bValue; },  
                               set : function(newValue){ this.bValue = newValue; },  
                               enumerable : true,  
                               configurable : true});
```

Now, the object `o` will have property `b`, and at the same time, it will also have another property `bValue`. The user (programmer) will be exposed only to 'b' and not to 'bValue' though he can still access bValue directly - I don't see how it can be prevented.

I understand that the property `b` and the property `bValue` may not always be same, but `b` would depend on the value of `bValue` because the getter and setter allow us to pre-process bValue before assigning the value to `b`.

The main question is, am I getting it right? Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a *closure*. This is a coding pattern that enables you to use private variables and only expose what you want to expose (public variables).

```
(function() {
    var bValue;

    Object.defineProperty(o, "b", {get : function(){ return bValue; },  
                                   set : function(newValue){ bValue = newValue; },  
                                   enumerable : true,  
                                   configurable : true}); 
})();
```

It creates a function and executes it immediately. This seems useless, but since functions introduce a level of *scoping*, `bValue` is not accessible anywhere but within the function this way.

The `o.b` property acts as a delegate between the developer and the value. You cannot access `bValue` itself. (Though in this example the getter/setter obviously act such that they *exactly* do the same as using `bValue` directly.)

http://jsfiddle.net/W4CSE/2/

Comment: ah...gotchha...thanks a lot. and it was quick too. thanks again.

Comment: +1: great answer. I was just wondering if a closure was the only way of doing this - seems to be what John Resig uses in [his example of the `Object.defineProperty()` method](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-objects-and-properties/).

Comment: @Chris Francis: Could you elaborate a little please? Private variables are almost synonymous with closures in JavaScript.

Comment: Well I'm really just thinking stylistically in terms of syntax. When I first saw `get` and `set` used inside `Object.defineProperty()`, I kind of naively assumed that the second arg (string) to `Object.defineProperty()` would be magically available to the third arg (property descriptor) - as in you could write `Object.defineProperty(o, "b", {get : function(){ return b; }, ...);` without actually creating a private backing store yourself! But of course that is just silly. :) Does that make sense?

Comment: @Chris Francis: It looks like that isn't really possible. Getters/setters are "black holes" by default and if you want to still store things you have to use an actual variable. You could also just make the getter return `123` at all times, and let the setter do nothing. They enhance flexibility, and part of this is that you can (rather, have to) use a custom backend.

Answer (score 3):

The idea is to wrap the code in a closure, thus hiding `bValue` from the world, like this:

```
var o =(function() {

    var o={},bValue;    

   Object.defineProperty(o, "b", {get : function(){ return bValue; },  
                               set : function(newValue){ bValue = newValue; },  
                               enumerable : true,  
                               configurable : true});


    return o;

})();
```

now you can reference `o.b` but not `bValue`